# Auto Increment in Master - Master

Tags: mysql, replication

I have set up Master Master replication and in order to avoid the duplicate primary key error, set the auto increment value to add 2 instead of default 1

```
auto_increment_offset=1
auto_increment_increment=2
```

This has helped the MMM setup to work as expected but it has some issues with the application that expects the linear sequence of numbers for auto ID's. Is there any solution to this problem?

Comment: "application that expects the linear sequence of numbers for auto ID's." --- rewrite it. Business logic should not rely on surrogate data.